# Check if Database Exists -- Engine Agnostic

Tags: sql

I know, I know...I did not even want to ask the question because I think there is no way to do besides the "try and miss" approach (try to make a query to the db and catch the error/exception if does not exists) but I felt like asking the pros.

So, is there a way, non db-engine dependent, to check if a db exists?

Comment: You answered your own question. It is "no" unless you go with try-and-miss.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to get it out and confirm with the experts; thanks everybody! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL assumes that there is already a connection to a specific database. So the only way to find out if a database exists lives outside standard SQL. For example there is [no CREATE DATABASE](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/sql-createdatabase.html#AEN62836) statement in standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the server or a specific database?

Whatever the answer to that question - Sure there is, just use the "DoesDBExist" function of my framework.  I have it in many different languages and platforms; do you need Android or C#.Net or some other?  But first, you need to snatch this pebble from my hand...

<sub>What you have is all there is, I'm afraid.</sub>

Comment: +1 Would have to agree with Cyber that you have to code this into your framework as "doesDbExist(...)".